# Ways to avoid "This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported"

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

This is what I'm trying to do

```
select something1,something2,account_id,
(select u.organization_id
          from public.sfdc_contact sfdcc
          join public.users u on u.email=sfdcc.email
          where sfdcc.account_id=account_id
          group by u.organization_id
          order by count(*)
      limit 1
          )
from something
```

Redshift prompted me the error because I was trying to ORDER BY count. But I can't have 2 columns in a subquery, any tips?

Comment: use joins instead (write a separate subquery and join it to the main query)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this structure will exactly meet your needs, but using "[window functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html)" such as ROW_NUMBER() OVER() can be used to supply single rows from joined derived tables (subqueries). For example:

```
SELECT
      s.something1
    , s.something2
    , s.account_id
    , d2.organization_id
    , d2.cn
FROM something s
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            organization_id
          , account_id
          , cn
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY organization_id ORDER BY cn) rn
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  u.organization_id
                , sfdcc.account_id
                , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY u.organization_id, sfdcc.account_id) cn
            FROM public.sfdc_contact sfdcc
            JOIN public.users u ON u.email = sfdcc.email
            ) d1
      ) d2 ON s.account_id = d2.account_id and d2.rn = 1
```

The use of COUNT() OVER() is probably unnecessary and this may be more pragmatic:

```
SELECT
      s.something1
    , s.something2
    , s.account_id
    , d2.organization_id
    , d2.cn
FROM something s
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
            organization_id
          , account_id
          , cn
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY organization_id ORDER BY cn) rn
      FROM (
            SELECT
                  u.organization_id
                , sfdcc.account_id
                , COUNT(*) cn
            FROM public.sfdc_contact sfdcc
            JOIN public.users u ON u.email = sfdcc.email
            GROUP BY
                  u.organization_id
                , sfdcc.account_id
            ) d1
      ) d2 ON s.account_id = d2.account_id and d2.rn = 1
```

Note also that if you wanted the HIGHEST count then change the order used in the row_number to DESCending:

```
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY organization_id ORDER BY cn DESC) rn
```